# Where Notepad++ keeps unsaved data?

Tags: windows, notepad++

In Notepad++ you can have tabs with unsaved data and when you reopen the app it is still there. I had quite a few tabs like that, when I installed Windows 11. I have disk backup.

Where can I find this unsaved data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your backup disk check for `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup`
and copy them over to the new Windows install.